# Is it possible to use 比如 at the end of a list of examples?

Tags: grammar, usage

Here's a random example sentence which uses 比如 from [Youdao.com](http://www.youdao.com/example/blng/eng/%E6%AF%94%E5%A6%82) (trimmed):

> 比如[数学](http://dict.cn/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6)、[物理](http://dict.cn/%E7%89%A9%E7%90%86)和[英语](http://dict.cn/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD)。
> Such as mathematics, physics and English
> <sub>bǐrú shùxué, wùlǐ hé yīngyǔ</sub>

In English, we can put "for example" at the end, so e.g. we could equally say the following:

> For example, mathematics, physics and English.
>
> Mathematics, physics and English, for example.

This is convenient when you forgot to say "for example" initially.  I'm wondering if this is possible in Chinese.

**Question**: Is it possible to use 比如 at the end of a list of examples?

I didn't find any examples on [Youdao](http://www.youdao.com/example/blng/eng/%E6%AF%94%E5%A6%82) nor [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E6%AF%94%E5%A6%82), so I think it's not possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: bkrs： for example; for instance; such as; suppose; say: maybe "such as"; 如 for "as" correctly reflects the Chinese word,(can 如 be at the end of a phrase?)  it
seems 比如说 could (although this maybe unusual) come afterwards

Comment: 如 can end a sentence as in idiom   **自愧弗如**   be ashamed of one's inferiority,e.g.  或许，这只是因为我觉得  **自愧弗如**  ，觉道自己没有吸引力罢了。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

在文章中，我們通常不那麼用。
We usually don't write in that way.

但在口語上，這是可能的。
But, it is possible in speaking.

它的目的是用來補充句子。
Its purpose is to supplement the sentence.

因為一開始講太快，沒能把順序講對，所以，在最後補上。
When we speak too fast at the beginning, and the order is not right, we supplement it at the end.

For example:

原本想要問：
Originally, I want to ask:

```
你昨天到哪裡去了？
```

但因說得很急，講成：
But I put it in a hurry, and say:

```
你到哪裡去了？
```

突然發覺不完整，就再補上「昨天」，變成：
I suddenly notice incomplete, then make up "昨天", to become:

```
你到哪裡去了，昨天？
```

「比如」也是一樣。
It is the same for 比如.

列出一些項目，但發覺這些只是其中的一部分，所以在最後補上。
List some items, but find that these are just a few of them, so make a final supplement.

```
問：妳喜歡什麼？  
Q: What's your favorite?

答：游泳、爬山、吃美食，比如（說）。  
A: Swimming, hiking, eating fine food, for example.
```

We usually don't write in this way because the grammar is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

We usually say the following:

```
  比如数学、物理和英语。
  例如数学、物理和英语。
```

These are equal to `Such as mathematics, physics and English`. We dont use `比如` at the end of a list of examples as I konwn.
(I wonder that it's possible to use `Such as` at the end of a list of examples?)

In oral Chinese, you could use

```
  数学、物理和英语，这些
```

to express the meaing of `Mathematics, physics and English, for example.`
But we dont use this in writing.

If you want to find some words for using at the end of a list of examples, maybe `等等` would be ok.
But note that:

```
  数学、物理和英语，等等
```

is not equal to `Mathematics, physics and English, for example.`
And you should not say `等等, 数学、物理和英语` too(so sad). To be more exact, `数学、物理和英语，等等` is equal to `Mathematics, physics and English, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

no,you can't say like :
数学物理和英语比如